# Javascript string trimming: Url and file path

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, trim

Here comes javascript noob again.

What I would like to do. 1:

```
// I will have many URLs as input
// I want to check if URL NOT end with slash
// if not then trim string after slash

var given_URL = "http://www.test.com/test"

var trimmed_URL = "http://www.test.com/"
```

What I would like to do. 2:

```
// I will have many file paths
// I would like to check if the path starts with unwanted dot OR slash
// If so, I would like to trim it

var given_path_1 = "./folder/filename.xxx"
var given_path_2 = "/folder/filename.xxx"
var given_path_3 = ".folder/filename.xxx"

var trimmed_path = "folder/filename.xxx"
```

I would like to know how to achieve these.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for the string after **domain**

Comment: I am trying to eliminate string after domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) using some [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
//replace all "/*" at the end with "/"
given_URL.replace(/\/\w+$/,'/');
//replace all non letters at the start with ""
given_path_2.replace(/^\W+/,'');
```

Answer (score 4):

1. For your first question, you should use the `lastIndexOf` method.

   **For example:**

   ```
   var index = given_URL.lastIndexOf("/");
   ```

   Check if `index ===  given_URL.length - 1` is true. If it is, you can use the `slice` method to cut your url.

   **For example:**

   ```
   var newUrl = given_URL.slice(0,index);
   ```
2. For your second question, you can check if `given_URL[0] === "."` or `given_URL[0] === "/"`. If this is true, then use the `slice` method to slice it.

   **For example:**

   ```
   var newUrl = given_URL.slice(1, given_URL.length - 1);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To trim until the last forward slash `/`, you could find the last occurrence of it and check if it the last letter in the string. If it is, you take the string until after that last occurrence.

To remove an optional dot (`\.?`), followed by an optional forward slash (`\/?`) from the start (`^`) of a string, you could do a replace with a regex of `^\.?\/?`.

```js
function trimToLastForwardslash(input) {
  var lastBackSlash = input.lastIndexOf('/');
  return lastBackSlash != -1 && lastBackSlash != input.length - 1 ? input.substring(0, lastBackSlash + 1) : input;
}

function trimFirstDotOrForwardSlash(input) {
  return input.replace(/^\.?\/?/, '');
}

var path = "http://www.test.com/test";
console.log(path + ' => trim last slash => ' + trimToLastForwardslash(path));

path = "http://www.test.com/test/";
console.log(path + ' => trim last slash => ' + trimToLastForwardslash(path));

path = "./folder/filename.xxx";
console.log(path + ' => trim first dot or slash => ' + trimFirstDotOrForwardSlash(path));

path = "/folder/filename.xxx";
console.log(path + ' => trim first dot or slash => ' + trimFirstDotOrForwardSlash(path));

path = ".folder/filename.xxx";
console.log(path + ' => trim first dot or slash => ' + trimFirstDotOrForwardSlash(path));
```